# Cannot Start Call from client app to teams user using ACS

Tags: c#, azure-communication-services

Using the guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-teams-interop?pivots=platform-windows

I am able to join a team meeting from my client app.

Now trying to start a 1:1 call with a teams identity on the client, to another teams identity (on teams); I've tried to use the StartCallAsync method (instead of JoinAsync) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-with-voice-video-calling-custom-teams-client

This example is in node - I'm using C# and it looks like the most recent beta build of the SDK does NOT have the `threadId` property exposed.

Here is the JS code

```js
call_ = await call_agent.startCall([{ microsoftTeamsUserId: calleeTeamsUserId.value.trim() }], { videoOptions: videoOptions, threadId: teamsThreadId });
```

and this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-communication-services/@azure/communication-calling/startcalloptions?view=azure-communication-services-js states that a threaded is required; however, no such `threadId` exists for c# SDK

The client goes from a connecting state to a disconnected state - the call never rings

Specific code to make the call

```csharp
StartCallOptions startCallOptions = new StartCallOptions();
ICommunicationIdentifier[] callees = new ICommunicationIdentifier[1]
{
     new MicrosoftTeamsUserIdentifier(*****)
};
call_ = await call_agent.StartCallAsync(callees, startCallOptions);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Communication Services have multiple types of Teams interop, which are in different phases of development by today (1/31/2022). Your combination of interop and programming language is currently not supported. Interop scenarios:

1. Ability of ACS users to join Teams meeting is generally available for all JS, .net, iOS, Android.
2. Ability of Teams user manage Teams VoIP calls, Teams PSTN calls, and Teams meetings via ACS JavaScript calling SDK is in public preview. Android, iOS, and .net calling SDKs do not support Teams identities.

You can learn more about the support in the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/interop/teams-user-calling